# Set an inputfield inside a vf controller

Tags: apex, visualforce, controller-extension

I have a field on a VF page when a user insert a value in that field and click a button, that value has to be pass to a variable inside the controller extension.
 The input field is:

```
<apex:inputField required="true" id="prodotto" value="{!Prodotto_contratto__c.Scelta__c}"/>
```

the button is:

```
<apex:pageBlockButtons location="top">
                <apex:commandButton action="{!addFromShoppingCart}" value="Aggiungi al Contratto" reRender="pselected,pinserted" />
            </apex:pageBlockButtons>
```

Now in the controller extension I have:

```
public Id prodotto{get;set;}
```

but I can't get the value inside the void function:

```
public void addFromShoppingCart(){
    Prodotto_contratto__c pr=new  Prodotto_contratto__c();
    pr.Name='prodotto in contratto';
    pr.Scelta__c=prodotto;
        System.debug(pr.Scelta__c);
    insert pr;
    System.debug('prodotto '+pr.id);    
    }
```

infact the system.debug value is null.
Please Help me, I'm becoming crazy on this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To use  you have to bind sObject fields with it. In your case you can declare an instance of type `Prodotto_contratto__c` and bind it's field with UI. Then you can access them in the controller.

```
<apex:inputField required="true" id="prodotto" value="{!prodotto.Scelta__c}"/>
```

Declare an object type of `Prodotto_contratto__c`

```
public Prodotto_contratto__c prodotto{get;set;}
```

Access prodotto fields as usual

```
public void addFromShoppingCart(){
    System.debug(prodotto.Scelta__c);   //this will give you the user input value       
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The **value** of the inputfield should match the field in the controller that you want to set. So

```
<apex:inputText required="true" id="prodotto" value="{!prodotto}"/>
```

will populate the controller field

```
public String prodotto{get;set;}
```

Comment: Can you bind string type class variables with `<apex:inputField />` ?

Comment: good point - should probably be inputText

Answer (score 1):

If the field is a lookup and you want to keep the salesforce functionality (search for record). You can also use:

```
Prodotto_contratto__c pr { get; set; }
pr=new  Prodotto_contratto__c();
```

And then use the field directly:

```
<apex:inputField required="true" id="prodotto" value="{pr.Scelta__c}"/>
```